# Remote port forwarding disconnected when run from cron

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I have installed FreeBSD and need to run regularly reverse shell to establish and keep alive SSH connection to the client (no public IP). When running the `ssh -R` script from the terminal, it works as expected, but when I run it as a cron command, the connection is established and disconnected right after that.

Here is auth.log from the server:

```
Jan 26 08:50:00 sshd[9696]: Accepted publickey for XXXX from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port XXXXX ssh2: RSA SHA256: xxxxxxxxx
Jan 26 08:50:00 sshd[9696]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user XXXX by (uid=0)
Jan 26 08:50:00 systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user XXXX by (uid=0)
Jan 26 08:50:01 systemd-logind[458]: New session 107 of user XXXX.
Jan 26 08:50:01 sshd[9794]: Received disconnect from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port XXXXX:11: disconnected by user
Jan 26 08:50:01 sshd[9794]: Disconnected from user XXXX XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port XXXXX
Jan 26 08:50:01 sshd[9696]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user XXXX
Jan 26 08:50:01 systemd-logind[458]: Session 107 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Jan 26 08:50:01 systemd-logind[458]: Removed session 107.
```

Do you have an idea, what causes this behavior and how to fix it?

Comment: `cron` might be a weird solution for this (it's not an action to be performed periodically, but a session that you want permanently). How about something like https://superuser.com/questions/37738/how-to-reliably-keep-an-ssh-tunnel-open

Comment: My intention is to run the script after reboot or in some longer intervals by using corn. Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, from some reason I am not able to install autossh. Anyway if I understand well, this tool is to keep ssh connection active. I am not sure if it would work if a disconnect signal is sent immediately after the connection is set up.

Comment: Well, I *assume* the problem is that `ssh -R` will also open an interactive shell to target server, and cron is not interactive, so it fails reading from stdin. `-N` switch might help. Logs from computer running `crond` might be useful as well.

Comment: Thanks for that. In the meantime I found this link: https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-tunnel-options/ I used the combination `ssh -f -T -N -R` and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - see posts above. Thanks